# How to create a model fragment in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I'm following this tutorial http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipsePlugin/article.html#eclipse-software-components-plug-ins , at step 7.5 I have to create new FRAGMENT MODEL but I  can't find that(eclipse4->Model) in my eclipse.I use eclipse Neon.I tried to download e4 from eclipse but it doesn`t work : http://www.eclipse.org/e4/downloads.php .

Comment: "[Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)"

Comment: Try to download from here http://download.eclipse.org/e4/snapshots/org.eclipse.e4.tools/latest/plugins/?d

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are working with "Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers" or "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers" or another package which does not contains the e4 developer resources. So either you install the e4 developer resources via "Help"-> "Install new software" -> "{version} - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/{version}" -> Filter text "e4" -> select "Eclipse e4 Tools Developer Resources" or you download the "Eclipse for RCP and RAP Developers" package from [here](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/).